# Return a key-press whilst another key is held down

Tags: javascript, dom-events

So what I need is to be able to hold down the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> key and the script needs to repeatedly spam the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> key as if I was doing it by tapping.

I have some code already written but I can't get it to work like I want.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {

      var i = 0;
       setInterval(() => {
           var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
           e.keyCode = 32;
           e.initEvent(++i % 2 > 0 ? 'keyup' : 'keydown', false, true);
           window.dispatchEvent(e);
      }, 35);
  }
});
```

So basically this works, when I press the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> it repeatedly presses the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> up and down, however it doesn't stop doing it when I release the space bar, however it doesn't actually start until I press the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> which means it's somewhat working.

I know the problem is with this line `e.initEvent(++i % 2 > 0 ? 'keyup' : 'keydown', false, true);`

but I've actually recovered this code from another project and can't figure out what it's doing or how.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent

Comment: I've taken a good look at this but I am not sure how to implement it into keyup keydown repeatedly until spacebar is let go.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need. Have a look. Event has a repeat property.

```js
let test = 1;
let temp = document.querySelector('.test');
temp.innerHTML = test;


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
    console.log(event.repeat);
    test += 1;
    temp.innerHTML = test;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class = 'test'>

<div>
```

Comment: This I'm assuming sends the spacebar to a console of some sort (I don't know much about java) I need it to actually send a spacebar press to the game I need this for (To simulate a user jumping repeatedly) So like I was just pressing the spacebar multiple times.

Comment: @SkylerKing Updated my answere. If you keep space pressed it keeps triggering. it might work for you. have a look at the code.

Comment: That seems to actually continually repeat the space bar whilst it's held down which is exactly what I want, but I need it to transfer into actually key presses that are sent to the game I am working on.

Comment: So I've thought about it more, perhaps if I add an EventListener for keyup to stop running the previous function, would that work and just be able to keep the original code?